# Call a controller in prestashop using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, prestashop

How can I call the method / function in the controller, I have a controller name `TestController.php`, then `Test.tpl` and `Test.js`. Also I am having a hard time on what to put on the url area.

I wanted to fetch the data from the controller using the ajax.

```
public function ajaxProcessTestMyAjax(){
  echo "test";
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $( ".view" ).click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "",
        data: {
            ajax: true,
            action: "TestMyAjax",
        },
        success: function(output){
            alert(output);
        }           
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'controller/action',
type: "POST",
datatype: 'json',
data: JSON.stringify({
                val1: "test1",
                val2: "test2"
            }),
success: function (jsonData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most important thing is to specify controller parameter:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
    url: baseUri + '?rand=' + new Date().getTime(),
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    dataType : "json",
    data: 'controller=cart&ajax=true&token=' + static_token,
    success: function(jsonData)
```

You may specify data as a string or an object (Doesn't reaelly matter, but creators of PS seemed to like strings).

When you specify controller PS automatically calls the appropriate controller. `controller` parameter may be sometimes called `tab` (in older versions?). Annother important thing is pass down token, which you can later check in your controller with special method (controller inherit it).

Another common way is to make a call to a file, and initialize PrestaShop inside your file. Then call some kind of module method.